# Is it right or wrong to create tables in the magento 2 database?

Tags: magento2, module, database, magento2.3.5

Guys I'm new to magento development and I'm trying to learn how to create basic modules and I'm trying to create a module that registers some customer information and then returns it to the administrator on the panel. But a question arose, is it wrong for me to simply go to the database and create a new table for this? or is there another safer and more practical way?

Comment: Yes you can always create a new table in magento and you can make as many tables as you need, just you need to follow the magento pattern to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practical way for creating a table in magento 2 you should follow its rules and regulations.
You need to create custom module and table schema, models and collections etc.
Here is a tutorial that will help you in this process. 
https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-create-insert-data-into-the-table-in-magento-2/

Thanks,
Vibhore